# Скопировать текст в буфер обмена при нажатии на div

Tags: javascript, jquery, span, copy

Есть блок **.t778__content** в котором заключена некая акция с заголовком **.t778__title** и промокодом **.t778__title span**

```
<div class="t778__content">
<div class="t778__title">Скидка 25% по промокоду
<span>TYKVA15</span>
</div>
<div class="t778__descr">При заказе от 1200 ₽. Действует на 1 заказ в сутки при онлайн оплате.</div>
</div>
```

Как при нажатии на блок с классом **.t778__content** скопировать span в заголовке **.t778__title**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(".t778__content").click(function(){
  let temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append(temp);
  temp.val($(".t778__title span").text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  temp.remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="t778__content">
<div class="t778__title">Скидка 25% по промокоду
<span>TYKVA15</span>
</div>
<div class="t778__descr">При заказе от 1200 ₽. Действует на 1 заказ в сутки при онлайн оплате.</div>
</div>
```